# Регулярное выражение только 2 слова через пробел

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, вёрстка

Нужно чтобы пользователь вводил имя и фамилию через пробел. Как написать Регулярное выражение для HTML атрибута pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<input required type="text" name="fn" pattern="^\S+ \S+$">
```

Допускается только 1 пробел между двумя группами не пробельных символов.

P.S. **Шарль д’Артанья́н** пропустит, а вот **Шарль Ожье́ де Батц де Кастельмо́р д’Артанья́н** уже нет ;)